# Динамический массив целых чисел

Tags: java, ооп

> Спроектируйте класс **Array**.
>
> Массив должен обладать двумя свойствами:
>
> ```
>    public int size
>    public int [] data
> ```
>
> В классе Array должен быть реализован метод:
>
> ```
>    public void add(int element)
> ```
>
> Данный метод должен помещать новый элемент в конец массива, а длину массива увеличивать на 1.
>
> В случае переполнения - необходимо увеличить длину массива data (необходимо выделить новый кусок большей длины, и скопировать в него данные, добавленные в data на предыдущих шагах)
>
> Проверка класса осуществляется следующим способом:
>
> ```
>   Создается экземпляр класса inst
>   Случайным образом формируется число N от 1 до 105
>   Случайные числа от 1 до 100 - N раз добавляются добавляются в массив методом add
>   Проверяется inst.size, inst.data[i], для i от 0 до N-1
> ```

Задача с одной стороны простая, но я запутался.

Насчет мейна и написанного в нем инстанса, где будет проходить проверка, все вроде просто:

Инстанс:

```
Array inst = new Array() ;
int r = случайное число;
inst.add(r);
System.out.println (inst.size) ;
System.out.println (inst.data[0]);
```

А вот что в классе **Array** написать, я не соображаю.

```
public class Array {
    public int size;
    public int[] data;

    public void add(int element) {
        int[] r = {1,2,3};
        r = Arrays.copyOf(r, r.length + 1);
    }
}
```

Естественно, это у меня не работает, хотя, как еще изменить размер массива, я не соображаю.

Попробовал так:

```
class Array{
    public int size;
    public int [] data;

    public void add(int element){
         if(size == data.length-1)
            Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length*2);
        data[size++] = element;
    }
}
```

Но все равно не проходит: вываливается `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Что у вас не работает? Это весь ваш код?

Comment: Да у меня все не работает...просто не пойму как создать нужный класс, чтобы в нем метод add был реализован так как в условиях задачи указано...

Comment: Ну правильно, что у вас выбрасывается `NPE`. У вас же `size` и `data` не проинициализированы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public class Array {
    public int size = 0;
    public int [] data = new int[0];

    public void add(int element) {
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, size + 1);
        data[size] = element;
        size++;
    }
}
```

Если хотите, можете ввести начальный размер массива и проверять, переполнится ли он:

```java
public int size = 0;
public int [] data = new int[10];

public void add(int element) {
    if(size == data.length)
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, size + 1);
    data[size] = element;
    size++;
}
```